# Can I actually resize an image with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing

I have a boss that is not computer savvy. I need to develop a webpage where he can log in and upload images. Some of the images need to be converted (resized) into thumbs. Is this even possible with JavaScript or jQuery or anything? I just need to constrain the width to 250px.

I am using jQuery and a gallery called jGallery.

I am currently designing the page to accept an uploaded image list that will save the files in the appropriate locations. I am hoping that I can at this time create a copy of the files and save them as a thumbs.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-crop-image-plugin/

Comment: Why don't you just set the width with css?

Comment: You are uploading it to what kind of back-end?

Comment: I would if it was my code. The code for the jGallery ask for two images. If I had designed it, it would have been different. It is what is in place and the boss likes it, so I can't do away with it.

Comment: I have several options for the back-end, such as Ajax & php, but would like to keep it as is using jQuery with JavaScript.

Comment: I am most likely going to design an interface using vb, but was just curious if JavaScript allowed binary saving. My gut says "No."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cropbox.js](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?7VoW4dx3), its a nice plugin for jQuery and easy to use :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this.

usage

http://elicon.blog57.fc2.com/blog-entry-195.html (Japanese)

```
var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        minified = MinifyJpeg.minify(image, length);
        enc = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + MinifyJpeg.encode64(minified);
        html = '<img src="' + enc + '">';
    }
    img.src = image
```

http://blog-imgs-51-origin.fc2.com/e/l/i/elicon/MinifyJpeg_ob.js

```
/*
 *TESTED(24/01/2013): FireFox, GoogleChrome, IE10, Opera
 *Minify a jpeg image without loosing EXIF
 *
 *To minify jpeg image:
 *target image must be loaded into Image instance before minifying
 *    var img = new Image();
 *    img.onload = function(){
 *        minified = MinifyJpeg.minify(image, length);
 *        enc = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + MinifyJpeg.encode64(minified);
 *        html = '<img src="' + enc + '">';
 *    }
 *    img.src = image
 *
 *MinifyJpeg.minify() - return Uint8Array
 *image - image base64encoded, it can be obtained "FileReader().readAsDataURL(f)"
 *length - the long side length of the rectangle
 *MinifyJpeg.encode64() - convert array to base64encoded string
 */

MinifyJpeg = {};

MinifyJpeg.minify = function(imageStr, chouhen)
{
    this.NEW_SIZE = parseInt(chouhen);
    this.rawImage = this.decode64(imageStr.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", ""));
    this.segments = this.slice2Segments(this.rawImage);
    var resized = this.resizeImage(imageStr);

    if (this.boolLostExif)
    {
        this.image = this.exifManipulation(this.resizedImage, this.rawImage);
    }
    else
    {
        this.image = this.array2ArrayBuffer(this.rawImage);
    }
    return this.image;
}

MinifyJpeg.keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP" +
                    "QRSTUVWXYZabcdef" +
                    "ghijklmnopqrstuv" +
                    "wxyz0123456789+/" +
                    "=";

MinifyJpeg.SOF = [192, 193, 194, 195, 197, 198, 199, 201, 202, 203, 205, 206, 207];

MinifyJpeg.getImageSize = function(imageArray)
{
    var segments = this.slice2Segments(imageArray);
    return this.imageSizeFromSegments(segments);
}

MinifyJpeg.slice2Segments = function(rawImage)
{
    var head = 0,
        segments = [];
    while (1)
    {
        if (rawImage[head] == 255 & rawImage[head + 1] == 218){break;}
        if (rawImage[head] == 255 & rawImage[head + 1] == 216)
        {
            head += 2;
        }
        else
        {
            var length = rawImage[head + 2] * 256 + rawImage[head + 3],
                endPoint = head + length + 2,
                seg = rawImage.slice(head, endPoint);
            segments.push(seg);
            head = endPoint;
        }
        if (head > rawImage.length){break;}
    }
    return segments;
}

MinifyJpeg.imageSizeFromSegments = function(segments)
{
    for  (var x=0; x<segments.length; x++)
    {
        var seg = segments[x];
        if (this.SOF.indexOf(seg[1]) >= 0)
        {
            var height = seg[5] * 256 + seg[6],
                width = seg[7] * 256 + seg[8];
            break;
        }
    }
    return [width, height];
}

MinifyJpeg.encode64 = function(input)
{
    var output = "",
        chr1, chr2, chr3 = "",
        enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "",
        i = 0;

    do {
        chr1 = input[i++];
        chr2 = input[i++];
        chr3 = input[i++];

        enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
        enc4 = chr3 & 63;

        if (isNaN(chr2)) {
           enc3 = enc4 = 64;
        } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
           enc4 = 64;
        }

        output = output +
           this.keyStr.charAt(enc1) +
           this.keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
           this.keyStr.charAt(enc3) +
           this.keyStr.charAt(enc4);
        chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
        enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
    } while (i < input.length);

    return output;
}

MinifyJpeg.decode64 = function(input) {
    var output = "",
        chr1, chr2, chr3 = "",
        enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "",
        i = 0,
        buf = [];

    // remove all characters that are not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, or =
    var base64test = /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g;
    if (base64test.exec(input)) {
        alert("There were invalid base64 characters in the input text.\n" +
              "Valid base64 characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '+', '/',and '='\n" +
              "Expect errors in decoding.");
    }
    input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

    do {
        enc1 = this.keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc2 = this.keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc3 = this.keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc4 = this.keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

        chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
        chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
        chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

        buf.push(chr1);

        if (enc3 != 64) {
           buf.push(chr2);
        }
        if (enc4 != 64) {
           buf.push(chr3);
        }

        chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
        enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";

    } while (i < input.length);

    return buf;
}

MinifyJpeg.resizeImage = function(imageStr)
{
    var img0 = new Image();
    img0.src = imageStr;

    var width = img0.width,
        height = img0.height,
        chouhen = (width>=height) ? width : height,
        newSize = this.NEW_SIZE,  //px
        canvas0 = document.createElement('canvas');

    if (chouhen < newSize)
    {
        this.boolLostExif = false;
        return;
    }
    else{
        var canvasWidth = parseFloat(newSize)/chouhen * width;
        var canvasHeight = parseFloat(newSize)/chouhen * height;
    }
    canvas0.width = parseInt(canvasWidth);
    canvas0.height = parseInt(canvasHeight);

    var context = canvas0.getContext("2d");
    context.drawImage(img0, 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    var resizedImage = canvas0.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

    this.boolLostExif = true;
    this.resizedImage = resizedImage;
    return;
}

MinifyJpeg.getExifArray = function(segments)
{
    var seg;
    for (var x=0; x<segments.length; x++)
    {
        seg = segments[x];
        if (seg[0] == 255 & seg[1] == 225) //(ff e1)
        {
            return seg;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

MinifyJpeg.insertExif = function(imageStr, exif)
{
    var imageData = imageStr.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", ""),
        buf = this.decode64(imageData),
        separatePoint = buf.indexOf(255,3),
        mae = buf.slice(0, separatePoint),
        ato = buf.slice(separatePoint),
        array = mae;

    for (var x=0; x<exif.length; x++)
    {
        array.push(exif[x]);
    }
    array = array.concat(ato);
    return array
}

MinifyJpeg.exifManipulation = function(lostExifImage, rawImage)
{
    var exif = this.getExifArray(this.segments),
        newArray = this.insertExif(lostExifImage, exif),
        bArray = this.array2ArrayBuffer(newArray);

    return bArray;
}

MinifyJpeg.array2ArrayBuffer = function(array)
{
    var bArray = new Uint8Array(array.length);
    for (var x=0; x<array.length; x++)
    {
        bArray[x] = array[x];
    }
    return bArray;
}
```

Comment: Pasted it. I can see it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can not actually crop the image and save it cropped.

You can however save it normal, and the resize it either with css - set it as a background to a div element and use the background-size property, scale (with the browser prefix) to scale it as a dom element, or just download any javascript gallery library at it should have it built in

Comment: isn't createWriteStream a node.js function?

Comment: My point was that node.js is actually a serverside language, while javascript and its jquery library are run on clientside, nothing else. If it does the job for you and you have node.js on the server its fine

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put a div of width = 250px; height = what you want.

Then, background-size: cover; will do all for you.

Little example:

HTML:

```
 <div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://robertgravesoratorio.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/owl-50267-1200x900.jpg');"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.image{
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/gudpumhL/1/

Note how the starting image was bigger than the result, and how the background-size cover scale the image to make it fit in the div.